# Get field settings of custom field via ElementInterface

Tags: plugin-development, craft-features, custom-fieldtype, custom-field

It is possible to get the field settings via ElementInterface in normalizeValue Method ?

I need these settings of my custom field from my plugin :

[image: I need the type and shop value.]

how i can get now these values inside normalizeValue ?

```
public function normalizeValue($value, ElementInterface $element = null)
{
    $type = $element; // Here comes the value of field settings (Type)
    $shops = $element; // Here comes the value of field settings (Shop)
    
    ...
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution the values are stored in **$this**:

```
public function normalizeValue($value, ElementInterface $element = null)
{
   $type = $this->type; 
   $shops = $this->shop;

   ...
   return;
}
```